# Output a string from code behind to a new page or window

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

Assume a string variable in code behind containing some HTML content such as

`Dim str1 As String = "<h3>hello</h3><p>some paragraph</p><table><tr><td>some table content</td></tr></table>"`

A saved file could be opened by registering a script such as

```
Dim script1 As String = "window.open('popupPage.html', 'myPopup')"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "someId", script1, true)
```

Is there any way to output this content in a new tab or window from code behind **without saving it to a file?**

Comment: Are you sure you want to create an entirely new browser window? Users often dislike those, as they seem like a popup ad and they're another full window to manage. It might be better to use some sort of in page window technnique, such as [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an empty string for a file name

```
'Declare a script with your variable
Dim script1 As String = "<script>var popwin = window.open('','myPopup');popwin.document.write('" & str1 & "');</script>"

'Call your script with ScriptManager for async postback from UpdatePanel
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "poptest", script1, true)

'Call your script with ClientScript for synchronous postback outside/without UpdatePanel
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "popuptest", script1, True)
```

check this [Call javascript function from asp.net code behind after server side code executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904915/call-javascript-function-from-asp-net-code-behind-after-server-side-code-execute/2905064#2905064)